# Response.redirect showing the previous page url in the address bar

Tags: c#, response.redirect

I used `Response.Redirect` in my code and it works fine but the `url` is not correct.It always shows the previous page `url`.

Here is my code.

```
Response.Redirect("Main.aspx?DocAddEdit=customer incident");
```

Please suggest.

I even tried `server.transfer`, but same thing happened.

Comment: This is strange as this is server.transfer feature where url does not get changed.

Comment: Are you sure you did not start with `Server.Transfer` originally and are having a version mismatch issue?

Comment: Sounds like you're using `Server.Transfer()` first then later in the same code block using `Response.Redirect()`. If that is the case then your results are as expected. You should post the entire code block for the method in question so we can get context.

Comment: I first tried response.redirect and then i tried server.transfer

Comment: @user3092654 Show the entire method. `Server.Transfer()` and `Response.Redirect()` don't work the same. If you're getting the same result then there is an issue in your code. Both methods are very old in ASP.NET so a major bug such as this would have been discovered long ago.

Comment: Are you doing any redirection from Main.aspx to home page?

Comment: No,I am doing it from Main.aspx to Main.aspx?DocAddEdit=customer incident

Comment: Than this question is wrong..It will always be same. Main.aspx to Main.aspx.Where are you redirecting?

Answer (score 0):

I find it highly unlikely that the `url` is the same. According to the [MSDN documentation on `Response.Redirect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9dwyts4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> ASP.NET performs the redirection by returning a 302 HTTP status code.

That means the browser actually performs the redirect and requests the new url.

`Server.Transfer`, on the other hand, will render and return the `url` you specify, in which case the url in the user's browser will stay the same.

Are you sure you tried `Response.Redirect` and not just `Server.Transfer`?

Comment: Yes..I am sure..I used both and both did the same thing

Comment: Edit your answer and show your code. Make it as complete but concise as possible so I can try to recreate this on my end.

Comment: I using Response.Redirect("Main.aspx?DocAddEdit=customer incident"); this in a catch block

Comment: When I perform `Response.Redirect("default.aspx?test=this is a test");` on my end it works as expected. You'll need to post more of your code in order for us to diagnose the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I came across the same issue with the previous URL remains after `Response.Redirect` and
I could solve it using `Response.End()` after the line `Response.Redirect()`.